# Adding actual files to a list, instead of just the file's string name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having issues reading the contents of the files I am trying to open due to the fact that python believes there is:

> "No such file or directory: 'Filename.xrf'"

Here is an outline of my code and what I think the problem may be:

1. The user's input defines the path to where the files are.

   ```
   direct = str(raw_input("Enter directory name where your data is: ))           
   path = "/Users/myname/Desktop/heasoft/XRF_data/%s/40_keV" \
                                                 %(direct)
   print os.listdir(path)
   # This lists the correct contents of the directory that I wanted it to.
   ```

So here I essentially let the user decide which directory they want to manipulate and then I choose one more directory path named "40_keV".

2. Within a defined function I use the OS module to navigate to the corresponding directory and then append every file within the 40_keV directory to a list, named dataFiles.

   ```
   def Spectrumdivide():
        dataFiles = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.xrf'):
                    dataFiles.append(file)
   ```

Here, the correct files were appended to the list '`dataFiles`', but I think this may be where the problem is occurring. I'm not sure whether or not `Python` is adding the NAME of the file to my list instead of the actual file object.

4. The code breaks because python believes there is no such file or directory.

   ```
   for filename in dataFiles:
       print filename
       f = open(filename,'r')    # <- THE CODE BREAKS HERE
       print "Opening file: " + filename
       line_num = f.readlines()
   ```

Again, the correct file is printed from dataFiles[0] in the first iteration of the loop but then this common error is produced:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '40keV_1.xrf'
```

I'm using an `Anaconda` launcher to run `Spyder (Python 2.7)` and the files are text files containing two columns of equal length. The goal is to assign each column to a list and the manipulate them accordingly.

Comment: Try seeing (by using print) what is inside the ´filename´ variable. I think that you are not keeping the path to the file (only the name) and that's why it can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the path name not just the file's name using the [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xrf'):
            dataFiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Hi and thanks! os.path.join worked. What value is root assigned in this code? The cwd?

Comment: @AustinS `root` here is the path to the directory. More infos in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)